# Can JWT be used as a common authentication medium for a application where i have both spring and node microservices?

Tags: node.js, spring, jwt, microservices

I have a Angular front end web app talking to both Spring and node microservices, while the spring microservice will handle user registration and sign in the node back-end will handle a lot of the post sign in activities. Can jwt be used as a medium to maintain authentication between all these sevices?

Comment: What do you mean by this? JWT can certainly be used as an authorization token in this context. Are you confusing authentication with authorization?

Answer (score 0):

In shortly, Authentication is the process of recognizing the user. Authorization is the user's privileges.You can use jwt in both process language-independent. When user log in using service written with java spring framework, service generates a jwt token. after that when the user calls the service written with java or nodejs, you can check user with jwt easily.

Answer (score 0):

JWT is the way to exchange encoded token between services. Certainly JWT can be used to do all this but the questions should be how.

Say you have frontend that talks to identity service (Azure AD/ Auth0/ Okta/Your own) and get you the JWT token. Each request that talks to backend service (or inter services communication) will carry the token . The backend service should be able to talk to identity provider and validate that token.